# _id is missing after doing actions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-redux

i'm currently creating my first MERN App, and everything is going well, until something happened, and i'm going my try to explain because i need help !

What i'm doing is a facebook clone, where you can post something, you can delete your post and you can update your post, the logic is simple, i call dispatch to pass the data to the actions, the actions pass the data to the backend, and the backend return something to me and it saves in my store, because i'm using redux

The problem is that, when i have 2 post, and i want to delete a post, or maybe i want to edit it, the other post dissapears, it's like it loses its id and then loses the information, then i can't do anything but reaload the page, and it happens always

[this is how it looks like, everything fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgeoH.png)

[Then, after trying to edit a post, the second one lost its information, and in the console, it says that Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop, and i already gave each post the key={_id}, but the post lost it and i don't know how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPPno.png)

Here's the code

Posts.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./Posts.css";

import moment from "moment";

// Icons
import { BiDotsVertical, BiLike } from "react-icons/bi";
import { MdDeleteSweep } from "react-icons/md";
import { AiFillLike } from "react-icons/ai";
import { GrClose } from "react-icons/gr";

// Calling actions

import { deletePost,  } from "../actions/posts.js";

// Gettin The Data From Redux
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const Posts = ({ setCurrentId }) => {
  const [animation, setAnimation] = useState(false);
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  const [modalPost, setModalPost] = useState({});

  // Getting The Posts

  const posts = useSelector(state => state.posts);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Showing And Hiding Modal Window

  const ModalWindow = post => {
    setModalPost(post);
    setModal(true);
  };

  // Liking the post

  // const Like = id => {
  //   dispatch(giveLike(id));
  //   setAnimation(!animation);
  // };

  if (!posts.length) {
    return <div>Loading</div>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="Posts">
        {/* // Modal window for better look to the post */}

        {/* {modal && (
          <div className="modalWindow">
            <div className="container">
              <div className="container-image">
                <img src={modalPost.image} alt="" />
              </div>

              <div className="information">
                <div className="container-information">
                  <div className="data-header">
                    <h2>
                      User <br />{" "}
                      <span style={{ fontWeight: "400" }}>
                        {moment(modalPost.createdAt).fromNow()}
                      </span>
                    </h2>
                    <span className="data-icon" onClick={() => setModal(false)}>
                      <GrClose />
                    </span>
                  </div>

                  <div className="message">
                    <h2>{modalPost.title}</h2>
                    <p>{modalPost.message}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )} */}

        {/*  */}

        {posts.map(post => {
          const { _id, title, message, image, createdAt, likes } = post;
          return (
            <div className="Posts-container" key={_id}>
              <div className="Fit">
                <div className="Fit-stuff">
                  <h2 className="Fit-stuff_title">
                    User <br />{" "}
                    <span style={{ fontWeight: "400" }}>
                      {moment(createdAt).fromNow()}
                    </span>
                  </h2>
                  <a
                    className="Fit-stuff_edit"
                    href="#form"
                    onClick={() => setCurrentId(_id)}
                  >
                    <BiDotsVertical />
                  </a>
                </div>

                <div className="Fit-data">
                  <h2 className="Fit-data_title">{title}</h2>
                  <p className="Fit-data_message">{message}</p>
                  {image ? (
                    <div className="Fit-img">
                      <img
                        onClick={() => ModalWindow(post)}
                        src={image}
                        alt=""
                      />
                    </div>
                  ) : (
                    <div></div>
                  )}
                </div>

                <div className="Fit-shit">
                  <span>
                    {animation ? (
                      <AiFillLike className="fullLightBlue" />
                    ) : (
                      <BiLike />
                    )}
                    {likes}
                  </span>
                  <span onClick={() => dispatch(deletePost(_id))}>
                    <MdDeleteSweep />
                  </span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Posts;
```

The form where i call update and create Post

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Filebase from "react-file-base64";

// For the actions
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { createPost, updatePost } from "../actions/posts.js";
import {
  Wrapper,
  FormContainer,
  Data,
  DataInput,
  SecondDataInput,
  FormContainerImg,
  FormContainerButtons,
  Buttons
} from "./FormStyled.js";

const Form = ({ currentId, setCurrentId }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: "",
    message: "",
    image: ""
  });

  const specificPost = useSelector(state =>
    currentId ? state.posts.find(p => p._id === currentId) : null
  );

  // Sending The Data And Editing The data

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (specificPost) setFormData(specificPost);
  }, [specificPost]);

  // Clear Inputs

  const clear = () => {
    setCurrentId(0);
    setFormData({ title: "", message: "", image: "" });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (currentId === 0) {
      dispatch(createPost(formData));
      clear();
    } else {
      dispatch(updatePost(currentId, formData));
      clear();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <FormContainer onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Data>
          <DataInput
            name="title"
            maxLength="50"
            placeholder="Title"
            type="text"
            value={formData.title}
            onChange={e => setFormData({ ...formData, title: e.target.value })}
          />
          <SecondDataInput
            name="message"
            placeholder="Message"
            maxLength="300"
            value={formData.message}
            required
            onChange={e =>
              setFormData({ ...formData, message: e.target.value })
            }
          />
          <FormContainerImg>
            <Filebase
              required
              type="file"
              multiple={false}
              onDone={({ base64 }) =>
                setFormData({ ...formData, image: base64 })
              }
            />
          </FormContainerImg>
          <FormContainerButtons>
            <Buttons type="submit" create>
              {specificPost ? "Edit" : "Create"}
            </Buttons>
            <Buttons onClick={clear} clear>
              Clear
            </Buttons>
          </FormContainerButtons>
        </Data>
      </FormContainer>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

My actions

```
import {
  GETPOSTS,
  CREATEPOST,
  DELETEPOST,
  UPDATEPOST,
  LIKEPOST
} from "../actionTypes/posts.js";

import * as api from "../api/posts.js";

export const getPosts = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.getPosts();

    dispatch({ type: GETPOSTS, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const createPost = newPost => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.createPost(newPost);
    dispatch({ type: CREATEPOST, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const updatePost = (id, updatePost) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.updatePost(id, updatePost);

    dispatch({ type: UPDATEPOST, payload: data });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const deletePost = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    await api.deletePost(id);

    dispatch({ type: DELETEPOST, payload: id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Redux Part

```
import {
  GETPOSTS,
  CREATEPOST,
  DELETEPOST,
  UPDATEPOST,
  LIKEPOST
} from "../actionTypes/posts.js";

const postData = (posts = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GETPOSTS:
      return action.payload;

    case CREATEPOST:
      return [...posts, action.payload];

    case UPDATEPOST:
      return posts.map(post =>
        action.payload._id === post._id ? action.payload : posts
      );

    case DELETEPOST:
      return posts.filter(post => post._id !== action.payload);

    default:
      return posts;
  }
};

export default postData;
```

My controllers in the backend

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import infoPost from "../models/posts.js";

// Getting All The Posts

export const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const Posts = await infoPost.find();

    res.status(200).json(Posts);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    console.log(error);
  }
};

// Creating A Post

export const createPost = async (req, res) => {
  const { title, message, image } = req.body;

  const newPost = new infoPost({ title, message, image });
  try {
    await newPost.save();
    res.status(201).json(newPost);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(409).json({ message: error.message });
    console.log(error);
  }
};

// Update A Post

export const updatePost = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  const { title, message, image } = req.body;

  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id))
    return res.status(404).send(`No Post With Id Of ${id}`);

  const updatedPost = { title, message, image, _id: id };

  await infoPost.findByIdAndUpdate(id, updatedPost, { new: true });

  res.json(updatedPost);
};

// Deleting A Post

export const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id))
    return res
      .status(404)
      .send(`We Couldnt Found The Post With Id Of ${id} To Delete`);

  await infoPost.findByIdAndRemove(id);

  res.json(`Post With Id Of ${id} Deleted Succesfully`);
};

// Liking A Post

export const likePost = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.params;

  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id))
    return res.status(404).send(`No post with id: ${id}`);

  const post = await infoPost.findById(id);

  const updatedPost = await infoPost.findByIdAndUpdate(
    id,
    { likeCount: post.likeCount + 1 },
    { new: true }
  );

  res.json(updatedPost);
};
```

Even though i've been trying to solve this problem for nearly 3.5 hours, i think that the problem might be in my Posts.js part, if you can help me, you're the greatest !

Comment: Couldn't say for sure because you don't show where the `updatePost` action is called, but you have a typo in your reducer, in `case UPDATEPOST`, it should be:  `action.payload._id === post._id ? action.payload : post`. Console log what your `posts.map()` returns to see.

Deleting should work fine from what it seems but in your actions you don't wait for the backend to respond. If the backend fails to delete a post, that won't be communicated to the frontend, but it'll still filter the post from the list.

Comment: Thank you ! and you're right i didn't show the form stuff where update and create stuff happen i apologize i already edited that part

And about the redux part, you were right as well, now it's working better, i try to edit and it does edit, i still have some problems like, the image doesn't update instantly, but that was a progress for sure

Comment: That is good to hear. You need a `loading` property in your state while the backend update is in progress because the image won't be updated immediately. It would be better if you structure your reducer in a more common/predictable way. I can definitely suggest you any traversy media tutorial on redux. Amongs many public projects you can see, I have a [personal project](https://github.com/alewis729/mdlive/blob/master/src/store/reducers/reducerSettings.js#L11) where you can see how I implement a `loading` piece of state. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks man, i'll try  to implement the loading stuff, and thank you for your support, firts time someone helped me to fix something, you're the greatest !